# Check existence of a record before returning resultset in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for a simple solution to replace my standardized junk way of validating whether a record exists before attempting to retrieve the data.  Currently, whenever one of my methods are called, I do something to the effect of...

```
private Record DoSomething(int id)
{
   if(data.Records.Count(q=>q.Id==id) > 0)
   {
      return data.Records.First(q=>q.Id==id);
   }
   return null;
}
```

...where I always check the count of the records to determine the existence of a record.  There has to be a more "elegant" way of doing this, without calling the database twice.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a lot of clean ways to handle this. If you want the first `Record` corresponding to `id` you can say:

```
Record record = data.Records.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
if(record != null) {
    // record exists
}
else {
    // record does not exist
}
```

If you only want to know if such a `Record` exists:

```
return data.Records.Any(r => r.Id == id); // true if exists
```

If you want a count of how many such `Record` exists:

```
return data.Records.Count(r => r.Id == id);
```

If you want an enumeration (`IEnumerable<Record>`) of all such `Record`:

```
return data.Records.Where(r => r.Id == id);
```

Comment: I think SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if more than one record is returned. Since it looks like an Id query it is probably safe to assume that SingleOrDefault would be okay, but FirstOrDefault is more general I think.

Comment: `Any(r => r.Id == id)` is preferred because it's more efficient (will result in an `EXISTS` instead of a `COUNT`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Record record = data.Records.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id);
return record;
```